# how to answer a question without reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

By way of example the following question, when read, made me feel like sharing a better answer. At least, which I believe it to be better.

https://serverfault.com/questions/40712/what-range-of-mac-addresses-can-i-safely-use-for-my-virtual-machines#

But no matter how I want to contribute, either as a relevant comment or as an answer, it simply does not allow me. I have not asked or answered any questions till now to have the required reputation.

How do I share ?

Comment: note that the question you linked to belongs to another site, not stackoverflow. reputation points arent the same between sites

Answer (score 11):

The notice at the bottom of that question says

> [Highly active question](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

So you'd have to do what it says i.e. earn 10 rep on Server Fault either through 5 accepted edits to posts or by writing a good question or a good answer to some other question on that site.

Protected questions are quite rare. You will be able to answer most other questions you encounter.

Comment: To clarify, the already answered link, which did not show in my search, has answer to my question and the former says: "Unfortunately, there are edge cases where brand-new users have something constructive to share and our system gets in the way of that. That's what happened to you. Sorry.". This is what I was looking. A negation is difficult to determine.